# Is "sample preparation" acceptable in section headings of a thesis?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

Every chapter in the result section of my thesis has a section called "Sample preparation". However, in this particular section, two or more kinds of samples are discussed.

Is the section name still technically valid or is there a usage like "samples preparation"?

Comment: I would just stick with the singular form. As a section heading, I don't see why it can't apply to more than one sample type.

Comment: You could switch to 'Preparation of Sample/s'. 'Samples preparation' is not ungrammatical, but _is_ unidiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

The singular is still correct. A Google search for "sample preparation" gives 60× as many hits as for "samples preparation", and most of the first-page hits for the latter were clearly not written by native speakers. This form is very common in compound nouns: "bus stop", "recipe book".